# yii2, active record, left join, как получить данные с запроса

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

я построил SQL запрос

```
return self::find()->select(['video.id', 'video.name', 'info_downloads.quantity'])
            ->leftJoin('video', 'video.id = info_downloads.video_id')
            ->orderBy(['info_downloads.quantity' => SORT_DESC])
            ->limit($count)
            ->all();
```

но в ответ получаю только video id

```
[0]=>
  object(api\modules\v1\models\InfoDownloads)#162 (10) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(9)
    }
    ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(9)
    }
    ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

как мне правильно получить данные , которые я указал в select

Answer (score 1):

Тут 2 варианта решения, первый это надо чтобы в вашей модели которая self были определены все поля что вы хотите вернуть т.е. именно имели такие свойства. Второй - просто перед all() вписать asArray()